# How to add a variable from portlet to page type URL - Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am creating a page type URL providing my URL. In URL i want to append a parameter which i will take it from a portlet. Can any one suggest me how to do this. Is it possible in the way i am doing or not?

Can any one suggest me any other way of doing this.

Regards,

Naveen

Comment: are you talking about creating "PortletURL"?

Comment: Can you tell us what do you mean by page type URL, and how are you creating it?

Comment: It is not at all clear as to what exactly you want to do. U have not specified what do you mean by page-type URL, since there is nothing called page-type URL in liferay? U have not specified where you are creating this URL? Have you gone through preliminary tutorials regarding portlet development and the life-cycle of a portlet? Do you know what is a "PortletURL"? What are renderURL, resourceURL and actionURL? Thanks

Comment: please give more information, It might help to include what you are planning to achieve with this - you're only stating *how* you want to achieve *something*.

Comment: Hi Lucky, No i am not using portleturl. In page i am giving it as url.

Comment: hi Niranjan, when i am adding a page from sitemap when i am trying to add a new page under it there are options for type in that i am keeping it as url.

Comment: hi olaf kock, i am trying to create a page which of type url, so i am asking a url from it. For calling the url i want some parameter to be appended to it so that it will be successful. I can do this using portletURL which will be a problem as in this case i have to write more then 10 portlet. To avoiding this i am writing like this.